# Django runserver hangs at “System check identified no issues (0 silenced).” for a while

Tags: python, django

I am not able to start manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000. I am using a MySQL database and I have imported all the required modules. I am trying to run quite basic application.

I am running python 3.7.3 on windows 10. Here is the error I am getting:

```py
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x0000000005A89E18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\aut
oreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mana
gement\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mana
gement\base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrat
ions\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrat
ions\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrat
ions\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrat
ions\recorder.py", line 62, in applied_migrations
    return {tuple(x) for x in self.migration_qs.values_list('app', 'name')}
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models
\query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\flgferre\Desktop\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models
\query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
MemoryError
```

I've seen a similar MemoryError around here, but I'm not using SQLite and I've already tried using DEBUG=False.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MemoryError with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816238/memoryerror-with-django)

Comment: I'm not using SQLite and I've already tried to set DEBUG = False to see if would run correctly. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved my problem by checking my dependencies. I believe that the code was stuck because of some kind of incompatibility among packages.